# Session lost when saving cookie

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, cookies

Upon successful login I want to save a cookie which contains username.

The cookie saves correctly and loads username correctly but loses session!

The code to retreive username is:

```
if (Request.Cookies["userName"] != null)
{
  txtEmail.Text = Request.Cookies["username"].Value;
  chkRemember.Checked = true;
}
```

The code to save username is:

```
HttpCookie aCookie = new HttpCookie("username");
aCookie.Value = txtEmail.Text;
aCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(5);
Response.Cookies.Add(aCookie);
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated, Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by session? ASP.NET Session? Or forms authentication session? Also what actions are you performing exactly? Are you closing the browser in between?

Comment: The ASP.NET session is being reset when navigating from the login form to the next form. This is only after adding the code above.

Comment: Is the above code in the login form, or somewhere else?

Comment: How do you see that ASP.NET session is being reset? Do you get a new SessionID or is a value you stored via Session["YourKey"] gone? I think you mix up Asp.net sesssion and are realy talking about not being logged in anymore.

Comment: @MalcolmFrexner not using .Net security, the session["mykey"] variables have all gone once the cookie has been saved and have navigated using response.redirect to the next form in the same webapp.

Comment: @M3NTA7 the sample code above is in the login form (not a .net login control).

Comment: Is the size of the data you save in one of your cookies large? There is a limit for cookie size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw an article recently that suggested that underscores in page names can cause problems in cookies, I haven't looked into this but it might be worth checking.

Alternatively, are you clearing your cookies if the user does not choose to be remembered?

I've seen an old example recently on MSDN showing delete method that will trash your session...[read the article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289495%28v=vs.71%29.aspx#vbtchaspnetcookies101anchor9).

If so be sure to only delete the cookie for the login otherwise you might be losing the cookie containing the sessionid.

A (very)quick translation into csharp of the article code:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++)
    {
        cookieName = Request.Cookies[i].Name;
        aCookie = new HttpCookie(cookieName);
        aCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
        Response.Cookies.Add(aCookie);
    }
```

With the solution being adding a check on the cookie name.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++)
    {
        cookieName = Request.Cookies[i].Name;
        if (cookieName == "username")
        {
            aCookie = new HttpCookie(cookieName);
            aCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
            Response.Cookies.Add(aCookie);
        }
    }
```

Also don't forget you can use subkeys within cookies.

Comment: Excellent thank you, the session variables were being lost when I was 'not remembering' the unsername cookie, I was deleting all the cookie objects including the session id. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

Bit of a wild shot, but are you moving from https to http? E.g. login form is https, following page is http

If so most browser will ditch session cookies.

Thanks,
Fran